# LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp – more tasks

Tags: android, rest, android-async-http

I would like to use AsyncHttpClient for more tasks in one Activity (I need to get and update data from different URL's via REST). But I'm not sure how to handle this. My idea was following:

```
private class Synchronize extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        prgDialog.show();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        url = "http://someurl";
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            client.post(getApplicationContext(), url, entity, "application/json", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String content) {
                    // do something
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int code, Throwable error, String content) {
                    // do something
                }

            }); 

        url = "http//otherurl";
        client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                // do something
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int code, Throwable error, String content) {
                // do something
            }
        });

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean b) {
        super.onPostExecute(b);
        prgDialog.dismiss();
        // refresh view
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure if I can do it like this. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: The whole point of AsyncHttpClient is avoiding the use of AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

If you already use AsyncHttp library you probably don't necessarily need use AsyncTask. What I did in my past two projects are extend from ResponceHandler class and init it with callback. You can make all request from ui thread if they not depend of each other and process in callbacks ui stuff or make next from callback but it should be synchronized. Here some example:

```
public class TrainersJsonHandler extends BaseJsonHttpResponseHandler {

    private OnGetTrainers mCallback;

    private Context mContext;

    private ObjectMapper mMapper;

    public TrainersJsonHandler(OnGetTrainers callback, Context context,
            ObjectMapper mapper) {
        mCallback = callback;
        mContext = context;
        mMapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String rawResponse,
            Object response) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable e, String rawData,
            Object errorResponse) {
        RestUtil.processFail(statusCode, headers, e, mContext, mCallback);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object parseResponse(String responseBody) throws JSONException {
        List<Trainer> result = parseTrainers(responseBody);
        if (result != null && mCallback != null) {
            mCallback.onFinishGetTrainers(result);
        }
        return null;
    }


    public List<Trainer> parseTrainers(String responseBody) {...}
}
```

and in activity I implemented interface and did something like this:

```
    @Override
            public void onFinishGetTrainers(final List<Trainer> trainers) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //do ui staff
                       //you can make here new request or refresh counter but should be synchronize
                    }
                });
            }
```

Hope it help.